# Superscript, subscript, and greek symbol all in one axis title in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, special-characters, axis-labels

I have the following title which I need for an axis for my plot in ggplot2: 
Plant δ34S (%0).

I'm unsure how to format it so that it appears properly in this question, but I need the 34 as as a superscript and the zero as a subscript. Therefore, I need a greek symbol, a superscript, and a subscript all in one axis title.

Although I know of various ways to code using expression, bquote, paste, etc, I've had little luck incorporating all three of these special cases. Any tricks to coding this properly?

Comment: (As always) Post an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
qplot(0, 0) + xlab(~ paste("Plant ", delta ^ 34, "S ", ("%"[0])))
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks...This worked with a slight modification for ggplot2 syntax: labs(x = ~ paste("Plant ", delta ^ 34, "S ", ("%"[0]))))

Comment: Have switched to ggplot2 for example.